# Area with Parametric Equations

Tags: calculus, parametric

The question I'm answering involves a parametric equation and these equations form a loop (according to the sketch). I was wondering if you were to integrate over an interval that was part of the loop would the value be the difference between the two areas??

[image]

The equations I got were:
$x=1-t^2$
$y= 2t-t^3$
And for example what if you integrated between x=1 and x=0, what does that value represent?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm afraid this question is hard to follow as written.  $x$ is a function of $t$, so you should be specifying the $t$ values, not the$x$ values.  Also, what is it that you want to integrate?  Are you trying to find the area inside the loop?  I don't know what you mean by "the difference between the two areas".  What two areas?  Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: Wait.  Are you trying to compute the area inside the loop and to the right of the $y$-axis?  Probably it's best to use Green's theorem.  Have you learned about line integrals yet?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear yeah it is that area you specified. I don't think I've come across line integrals yet.                                                                          Sorry my question wasn't super clear, let's say you did the integral from t=x(0) to t=x(1) of y dx/dt dt (how we've been taught parametric) what area of that graph will that value represent?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this the way you have in mind, you have to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ in the interval of interest, so let's start by figuring out what the interval is.  There are two points on the curve where $x=0$, corresponding to $t=1$ and $t=-1$.  There is one point where $x=1$, corresponding to $t=0$, so we are interested in $-1\leq t\leq 1$.  Note that $x(-t)=x(t)$ and $y(-t)=-y(t)$ so if $(x,y)$ is on the curve, so also is $(x, -y)$.  That is, the curve is symmetric about the $x$-axis, so the area in question is twice the area in the first quadrant, and we can restrict our attention to the case $y\geq0$, that is $0\leq t\leq1$.

We have $$\begin{align}
y&=2t-t^3\\
&=t+t(1-t^2)\\
&=t+tx\\
&=t(1+x)
\end{align}$$
Further, $$\begin{align}
t^2&=1-x\\
t&=\pm\sqrt{1-x}\\
t&=\sqrt{1-x}
\end{align}$$
since $t\geq0$.

Combining these two results gives $y=(1+x)\sqrt{1-x}$ so the area in question is $$2\int_0^1(1+x)\sqrt{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ which you should have no trouble computing.

In this case, we were able to solve for $y$ explicitly in terms of $x$.  Usually, that would not be possible, and other methods that you haven't learned yet would be needed.